# How do I stop triggering my event-based VBA code when there's an error in the spreadsheet?

Tags: vba, email, excel

I have a set up a code to automatically send an email when a cell reaches a certain value. (below)

If an error is made and the cell is then deleted, it sends the email as well.  What do i need to add to the code to stop it sending if i delete the value from the cell?

Thanks in advance.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

If Not Application.Intersect(Range("M4:M368"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 1000 Then
        Call Fuel_LevelW01D
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: add this `And Target <> ""` in your second `IF` statement.

Comment: @L42: I prefer `Not IsEmpty(Target)`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett yes of course :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You don't need to test for `IsNumeric`
- Best to run two separate `IF's` rather than an `AND` as there is no point testing for `<1000` unless the cell has a value

*updated code*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("M4:M368"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    If Len(Target.Value) > 0 Then
        If Target.Value < 1000 Then Call Fuel_LevelW01D
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I was under the impression that when the first condition of an `AND` statement returned false that the second is never evaluated.  It would only look at both conditions if it was an `OR` statement.  So breaking it up to two `if` statements doesn't have any advantage speed or otherwise.

Comment: @PortlandRunner VBA actually does not have [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), which is what you describe.  Instead, it evaluates BOTH criteria and then checks the whole boolean statement.  This has some rather unfortunate consequences.  Imagine you were trying to say `If 5<4 And 1/0 Then`.  Because VBA evaluates each subexpression instead of short circuiting, that line throws a runtime error even though the first criteria is always false. See the chart [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: @Blackhawk thanks for the explanation and the link.  It's been helpful.

Comment: The best reference I have seen re strings in VB/VBA [here](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/loopopt.html). Includes short circuiting